# How to pass an array of PHAssets to another ViewController using Segue

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, segue, assets

I need your help! I am trying to pass an array of selected PHAssets from my first ViewController to the next one.
I am declaring the array here:

```
import UIKit
import Photos
import BSImagePicker

class ViewControllerSelectPhotos: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var btnSelect: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var btnStartGame: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var lblStatus: UILabel!

var SelectedAssets = [PHAsset]()
```

And add the PHAssets with a pod named BSImagepicker here:

```
@IBAction func btnSelectPhotos(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let vc = BSImagePickerViewController()

    self.bs_presentImagePickerController(vc, animated: true, select: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in

    }, deselect: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in

    }, cancel: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in

    }, finish: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in

        for i in 0..<assets.count
        { self.SelectedAssets.append(assets[i])
        }

    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Then I am using the prepare for segue function to pass the array:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any? ) {
if (segue.identifier == "SegueToViewControllerGame") {
        (segue.destination as! ViewControllerGame).SelectedAssetsGame = (SelectedAssets as AnyObject) as! [PHAsset]
   }
}
```

In the second ViewController I want to save the array SelectedAssets in the array SelectedAssetsGame:

```
class ViewControllerGame: UIViewController {

var SelectedAssetsGame: [PHAsset] = []
```

I always get a `NSInvalidArgumentException`. What can I do?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What does `SelectedAssets` contain? Why are you casting to `AnyObject` if it already contains `[PHAsset]`

Comment: SelectedAssets contains PHAssets from the Photo Library. I am casting because Xcode suggest it. Even if I don't do it, I get the same Exception.

Comment: Please show/edit the code where you declare and add your PHAsset objects to your `SelectedAssets` array. Also your `SelectedAssets` variable declaration.

Comment: Okay, I did. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `btnSelectPhotos` method, instead of doing a for loop, you can simply assign the assets to your `SelectedAssets` variable like this:

```
finish: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in    
    self.SelectedAssets = assets
}
```

And then pass your `SelectedAssets` object to your destination view controller:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any? ) {
    if (segue.identifier == "SegueToViewControllerGame") {
        (segue.destination as! ViewControllerGame).SelectedAssetsGame = SelectedAssets
    }
}
```

**EDIT (Solution):**
Make sure you have connected your `IBOutlets` properly (without any old invalid outlets) and you pass correct parameters to your method calls.

Comment: Thank you! But it is still not working. The app crashes with this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Remembar.ViewControllerSelectPhotos btnStartGame:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9d7be0ac30'.

Comment: Have you connected your IBOutlets properly? Are you passing correct parameters to your `btnStartGame` method?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I found an old reference that caused the error. Now it all works fine. Thank you very much for your time and help, I appreciate that!

Comment: @badhanganesh Hi sorry to disturb you, Please do you mind if I ask one question related to `TLPhotoPicker`

Comment: @Newbie Yes pls.

Comment: @badhanganesh First of all thank you. my question is in `TLPhotoPicker` is it possible we can directly open camera view instead of first library than camera? For library or camera on button tap function I use `CustomPhotoPickerViewController()` but I also want direct camera view?

Comment: @Newbie I am not familiar with that library. But from what I have seen from the screenshots and demos, it is upto the lib owner to provide that function (opening camera directly). 

Perhaps you can create an issue in GitHub if you think that it is needed, or use another lib that satisfies your needs.